# Studying abstract algebraic varieties.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

On page 145 of "An Invitation to Algebraic Geometry" I do not see how the open cover of the manifold is isomorphic to open balls of $R^{n}$. Please correct me if I'm wrong - the text says any union of open sets is open so does that mean the balls are the complement of unions of circles greater than or equal to a fixed radius or complementary sets of circles *except* for ones less than given radii; how are the balls of $R^{n}$ vanishing sets of a function here which are open?

I can't get why a space is isomorphic to an affine algebraic variety if the Zariski topology isn't used!

[p.145](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoTqg.png)

Comment: Can you post a picture or provide more context for those of us who don't have the book?

Comment: I just tried to look this up, but I must echo the previous comment. In the version I have, p. 145 begins the appendix on sheaves, which says nothing about open balls or manifolds.

Comment: Please do not assume that (1) we all know what book you are talking about and (2) we have said book. Post an actual question, without linking to a picture.

Comment: The book defines things as follows :  A smooth manifold is a ringed space that can be covered by open sets $U_i$, with each $U_i$ isomorphic as a ringed space to an open ball $B \subseteq R^n$ with its sheaf of smooth functions.

Comment: Which topology makes the "open ball" open?

Comment: The usual one? Also @David Lui I gotta say that's a weird definition for a manifold. What happened to Poincaré's good old subsets of R^n?